# Send direct message on Twitter for iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am developing iOS Application in which I need to send direct message to those I am following. I done this by this `TWRequest` but this is obsolete and not exist in 7 and 8. So kindly suggest me any helping material. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fabric for direct message on Twitter.Use below link
https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/ios

You have to first sign in through Fabric & you then you have to download Fabric app for your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FHSTWitterEngine](https://github.com/fhsjaagshs/FHSTwitterEngine) , I have used this library in my projects and working fine for iOS7 and above.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url:String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
let params = ["status": "This is my message"]
var clientError : NSError?

let request:NSURLRequest = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL:url, parameters: params,error: &clientError)

    Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
            (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                do {
                    let json : AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                    print("json:\(json)")
                } catch {

                }
            }
            else {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }
    }
}
```